# Unable to start application/Native Module Cannot Open Null

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am implementing Track Player into one of my screens but when I try to render it, I got "Unable to start application/Native Module Cannot Open Null" error. My end goal is to implement 2 tracks on this page with play and pause functions as well as artwork. I've cleared the cache and restarted my emulator and even ran it in the web browser

Here is my code:

````
import Icon from 'react-native-ionicons'
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';i
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';



const tracks = [
    {
        id: 1,
        url: require("../assets/tracks/Podcast95 .mp3"),
        title: 'Episode95',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        url: require('../assets/tracks/Podcast100.mp3'),
        title: 'Episode100',
    },
];

TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
    stopWithApp: false,
    capabilities: [TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY, TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE],
    compactCapabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
    ],
});


const Episode = ({navigation}) => {
  const setUpTrackPlayer = async () => {
    try {
      await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
      await TrackPlayer.add(tracks);
      console.log('Tracks added');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setUpTrackPlayer();

    return () => TrackPlayer.destroy();
  }, []);

    
    
    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <View>
                    <Image
                     style={styles.artworkImg}
                     source={require('../assets/JColeSlam.jpg')} />
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => TrackPlayer.play(id,1 )}>
                        <Ionicons name="play" size={30} color="#777777" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Ionicons name="pause" size={30} color="#777777" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      
    );
}; 

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#222831'
    },
    mainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    artworkImg: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        borderRadius: 15,
    }
})


export default Episode; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

run npm install
it can work for you
and also check third party dependencies are installed or not